# How to know which s3 bucket trigger which lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

How to know which s3 bucket trigger which lambda without going to all lambdas?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Can you elaborate little bit and give me the step? as i ma not seeing where to see the list of triggers. As i am not much familiar to AWS.

Comment: Go to the S3 console, click your bucket, go to the **Properties tab**, click **Events**. A list of triggers on the bucket will be displayed.

Comment: There is no events in the properties tab. There is only Versioning, Server Access Logging, static website hosting, Object Level logging and default encryption.

Comment: Scroll Down to see more options.

Answer (score 4):

This can be a bit difficult since the command line options for Lambda require that you use `aws lambda get-policy` in order to find out which resources are allowed to perform the `lambda:InvokeFunction` action on a given function. These permissions aren't shown as part of the lambda configuration for `aws lambda get-function-configuration`. Use `bash` and `jq` to get a list of functions and spit out their allowed invokers. Like this:

```
aws lambda list-functions | jq '.Functions[].FunctionName' --raw-output | while read f; do
  policy=$( aws lambda get-policy --function-name ${f} | jq '.Policy | fromjson | .Statement[] | select(.Effect=="Allow") | select(.Action=="lambda:InvokeFunction") | .Condition.ArnLike[]' --raw-output )
  echo "FUNCTION ${f} CAN BE INVOKED FROM:"
  echo ${policy}
done
```

This will list the arn of the resources that are allowed to use the action `lambda:InvokeFunction` on the all Lambda functions returned from `list-functions`.

Answer (score 4):

You can look into these triggers under a bucket events itself. When you open a **s3 bucket**, navigate to **Properties** and under that **Events**. You can however delete or edit the resource triggered from that panel. Hope it helps

Comment: It's called "Event notifications" now

Answer (score 0):

When you set up triggers on your S3 Bucket, you can select which Lambda function is invoked.

Check out this document for more information: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html.

Here's a more comprehensive document that deep dives on S3 event notifications: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/enable-event-notifications.html

> If you select the Lambda Function destination type, do the following:
>
> In Lambda Function, type or choose the name of the Lambda function that you want to receive notifications from Amazon S3.
>
> If you don't have any Lambda functions in the region that contains your bucket, you'll be prompted to enter a Lambda function ARN. In Lambda Function ARN, type the ARN of the Lambda function that you want to receive notifications from Amazon S3.
>
> (Optional) You can also choose Add Lambda function ARN from the menu and type the ARN of the Lambda function in Lambda function ARN.